# What is this chord progression called?

Tags: chord-theory, harmony, chord-progressions

During the intro (0:00 ~ 0:04),

The chord progression is: I maj7 -> IV maj7 -> b VII maj7-> b III maj7 -> b VI maj7 -> II7-> b II maj7 -> V

What is this called? Is this an example of an extended "II-V"?

Where can I find more examples like this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a cycle of fifths (or fourth if you want to look at it this way). It is a chain of chords with roots a fifth apart. The whole thing and parts of it are commonly used. The presence of the flats doesn't matter so much, it's the nominal fifth progression that matters.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. Do you know some other similar examples too?

Comment: The obvious diatonic cycles, major: I,IV,vii0,iii,vi,ii,V,I or in minor (where the  last three chords work well) i,iv,VII,III,VI,ii0,V,i. The "ragtime" progression: I,III7,VI7,II7,V7.I or the I,vi,ii,V or I,vi,IV,V which are popular.

Comment: Yeah but the attached song used non-diatonic chords, I maj7 -> IV maj7 ->( b VII maj7-> b III maj7 -> b VI maj7 -> II7-> b II maj7). I am trying to see more examples in songs and wondering which scales should be used in such a case. Should it be interpreted as modal interchange and used with a minor scale?

Answer (score 0):

**These are all variations of the circle of fifth:**

(I would also subsum the tritonus substitution and the chromatic scale downwards... )

with a  less sophisticated and more generous  analysis we could get a better understanding of the harmonic process.

looking for another piece with a similar progression?

here is one at 1:42 min

the bass plays the circle of fifth: B-E-A-D-G-C-F-E

organ, piano and guitar play: B7-Bb7-A7-Ab7-G7-F#-E